# subprocess.run with stdin input doesn't process

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to run a command in python:

```
from subprocess import run, DEVNULL
run(["./rarcrack",'walks.rar'], text=True, input='nano1 nano2', stdout=DEVNULL)
```

The command doesn't seem to process the `stdin` though (It says no more words, whereas in the example below it says successfully cracked).

I decided to do this because I'm under the impression that:

1. The bash pipe redirects `stdout` to `stdin` and
2. `./rarcrack` takes an argument from `stdin` because a command like
   `echo 'nano1 nano2' | ./rarcrack walks.rar` works.

And I don't think I can pass in the words as another argument (I don't know any C).

The program is [here](https://github.com/hyc/rarcrack)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you discard any results with `stdout=DEVNULL`. You only see the error output, not the successes.

Comment: I've removed it and it's not that. The stdout=DEVNULL prevents the version number stuff from printing. The C program still outputs stuff with DEVNULL anyways as well (it outputs no more words).

Comment: That message goes to standard error, as you can see from the source code, and as I tried to explain in this answer.

Comment: I dont know C so sorry if I seem obtuse but by message do you mean the 'no more words' message? I think it actually is supposed to take from standard input (although Im not sure) but somehow is not processing the standard input because without setting input, it prints an error that specifies usage. Do you mean it takes input from standard error??

Comment: I don't think there are any successes because if I supply it with a long wordlist, it hardly takes any time to complete, and also if it succeeds, the file should be unrared.